# SSRS Report Management and Deletes

Tags: sharepoint-server, reporting-services

**How do I properly delete reports and data sources when deployed to a SharePoint list?** There doesn't appear to be any report control from the App service management page and while I can certainly just do a delete on the library item, it doesn't remove the entry from the SSRS Catalog in the RS database.

A separate issue, which I'm trying to resolve, or at least not run into again, is some reports were removed from the RS catalog, somehow(??). I have execution details in the Execution logs for IDs that do not exist in the Catalog.

All reports were deployed to SharePoint 2013 from SSDT 2012.

**What I'm interested in is if there is a way to delete reports and data sources that propagate changes to the RS database.** I'm reporting off the report executions and I get multiple entries for the same report where the name is the same, but GUIDs/PKs are different causing reporting issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is SSRS running in integrated mode? The first thing I would do is stop and start the Reporting Services service on whatever server you have running it. This can help clear up any issues with SSRS caching stuff, which was a huge problem for me in the past when I was trying to delete a site collection, recreate it and re-configure reports on top of it - not quite the same as your issue but it's worth a shot.

If that doesn't help, you can leverage the Reporting Services API - in integrated mode, this is located at:

[yourserverurl]/_vti_bin/ReportServer/ReportService2010.asmx

This service has a DeleteItem method that should take care of deleting reports - a quick console app could do the trick.

For more info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt246820.aspx#M:ReportService2010.ReportingService2010.DeleteItem(System.String)